# links to other AMP pages in an AMP article

Tags: amp-html

I have several non-AMP pages within a topic. My non-AMP pages will have links within the body of the article to other non-AMP pages in the same topic. Should the AMP versions of the pages link to the other AMP pages in the same topic or should all links in the articles point to the non-AMP (canonical) versions of the pages?

```
Using the following link formats for the example:  
Non-AMP version: /muffins/blueberry/  
AMP version: /muffins/blueberry/amp/
```

**/muffins/blueberry/** has a link to **/muffins/strawberry/**
Should **/muffins/blueberry/amp/** link to **/muffins/strawberry/amp/** or to **/muffins/strawberry/**?

Or said another way, if a visitor comes to your site on an AMP page, do you continue to offer them links to other AMP versions of your pages or should you switch them over to the full pages as soon as possible?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it is up to you to decide since no where in the docs does it state that we must have links leading to one or the other. If it helps, we decided to have all links within the AMP page link back to the canonical page and our pages are appearing in the carousel perfectly fine.

If you look at the [AMP HTML Specs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html), it only states that links cannot begin with `javascript:`.

Comment: Do you think there would be any disadvantage to linking to other amp page versions? I couldn't find much discussion about it in my searches. Knowing my luck, whatever I decide to do will turn out to be the wrong way. :-/

Comment: I would say the advantages/disadvantages of linking to your other AMP page pages depends on you, whether or not your AMP pages are fully completed, and whether you want users to be using the AMP pages more or the canonical pages more. From my observations, all of the AMP pages on the carousel I have visited from other publishers all link back to the canonical page.