# AMP Page. Best Practice to link to another pages of the site

Tags: amp-html

In my site have AMP version of all pages.

When in an AMP Page there are links (href) to another pages of the site (**like related articles**). Those links must point to the AMP version or to the regular version?

On the Internet I found many AMP implementations that link AMP pages with non-AMP version **despite AMP versios exists** but I don't figure out why.

I think that if a mobile user visit an AMP page then in that page the links to
related pages of the site must point to the amp version too, for improve UX but I don't sure about what is te best practice to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Note: this question is not about local amp site vs amp CDN but it's about linking pages inside the local site. Please read it carefully and sorry if my english is not good enough.

Comment: I think this was answered here: [links to other AMP pages in an AMP article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063344/links-to-other-amp-pages-in-an-amp-article)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [links to other AMP pages in an AMP article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063344/links-to-other-amp-pages-in-an-amp-article)

Answer (score 1):

I make all my AMP pages point to HTML versions of my site, mainly because I don't believe in pointing to non-canonical links.

One of the main benefits of AMP is how Google caches everything, and of course you loose this if you point to an AMP page on your domain.

One thing to consider is how alike your AMP and HTML pages are, for me they are very similar ([html](http://tosbourn.com/brighton-ruby/), [amp](http://tosbourn.com/amp/brighton-ruby/)) so I don't think a user is going to mind.