# What is the recommended way to convert non amp website to amp ? Only landing pages should be changed or all

Tags: amp-html

We have converted our website named http://www.ifsccodebank.com/ into amp version http://www.ifsccodebank.com/amp. And our amp version consists of several navigational links which are also amp based. Whenever a user fires a query based on specific keywords, the amp link will be shown to the user and that link will be from Google AMP CDN Cache, but the other links are simply amp links based on our domain. So, my question is that other links can be amp or non-amp ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [links to other AMP pages in an AMP article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063344/links-to-other-amp-pages-in-an-amp-article)

Answer (score 1):

Well, It will depends on you, you can either use amp links or non-amp links. It is not stated in the [AMP documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec) that you cannot use non-amp links with your amp sites.

But please be noted that AMP is supposed to deliver faster page rendering when compared to the render time of the same web page using conventional HTML/CSS/JS.

Here is an [example](http://www.ebay.com/sch/amp/Camera-Drones/179697/bn_89951/i.html) of amp site that have a link which is not an AMP.

Hope this information helps you.