# Link from AMP-Page to AMP-Page?

Tags: html, amp-html

i.e. I've some AMP-Pages

```
 amp-index.html
 amp-subpage1.html
 amp-subpage2.html
 amp-subpage3.html
```

should I link from *amp-index.html* directly to the amp-subpages or is it better to link to the non-amp-pages?

Comment: The amp page should only be the entry point to your website. If you combine AMP with PWA you have the ideal solution right now.

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/pwa-amp

Comment: by the way this question was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063344/links-to-other-amp-pages-in-an-amp-article

Comment: @adithyasai - [please stop adding](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46340881/revisions) the [tag:amp] tag onto questions which refer to the [tag:amp-html] tag. I'm going to revert changes where this tag has been incorrectly added. Christoph - sorry for an unrelated comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you because in AMP documentation there is no rule for this situation or no restriction, You can link AMP page to another AMP page for fast execution.

According to AMP documentation if you have only one AMP page than your amp and non amp url is same. For more detail [**Make your page discoverable**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)

***According to my point of view you can link AMP-Page to AMP-Page for fast execution.***

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on you how fast you want to execute your page and how efficiently you want to show your content to the user.

If you like to see the variation between the content representation in AMP vs Normal version you can refer to the following links: http://akashshivanand.com/google-news/google-mobile-search-ui-redesign/amp/ and http://akashshivanand.com/google-news/google-mobile-search-ui-redesign/

**Conclusion**

- You can link to the `AMP` version if Content and the execution speed *(in some cases)* matters a lot for you.
- You can link to the `Non-AMP` version if design and functionalities matter a lot for you.

Have a great day Ahead!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can link your amp subpages for fast view rendering (**But its not mandatory**)

Answer (score 0):

Other than speed it has SEO benefits as well. AMP pages will rank better than normal pages on mobile.