# How to link Google AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I want to link from 1 Google AMP page to another Google AMP page, to optimize the speed of the user's browsing experience.

I already read these articles: [links to other AMP pages in an AMP article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063344/links-to-other-amp-pages-in-an-amp-article) and https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec and [Link from AMP-Page to AMP-Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340881/link-from-amp-page-to-amp-page). But these posts just cover whether one SHOULD link AMP to AMP, whereas I'm asking HOW to link.

Before I rewrite my links, what way should I link between AMP documents? Like this:

`https://www.foo.com/amp_document.html`

or like this:

`https://foo-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/foo.com/amp_document.html`

I'm not sure if Google will treat an AMP page that is visited from another internal AMP page differently than when the user visits an AMP page from Google's SERPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the AMP pages as

> https://www.foo.com/amp_document.html

URLs like

```
https://foo-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/foo.com/amp_document.html
```

are created when a user visits the link directly from the search result. You don't need to bother about that.